# Box2D OpenGL 2D rotation weird behavior

Tags: opengl, box2d

**Edit**
**Solved. Source code updated to working version!**

I'm trying to make a simple game engine for my next game using OpenGL and Box2D.

Problem is I can't get working these two well. If i turn OpenGL rotation off, everything looks as I'd except it in real worl. Problem is with rotation on.

http://cl.ly/image/0I0M3C3K1c3c - rotation off
http://cl.ly/image/421v321t201D - rotation on

I don't know if it's Box2D or OpenGL problem but I think right box shouldn't be rotated if it's on a flat ground in calm state or it's clearly violates law of physics. This is not only one problem but this one is clearly visible with picture only.  I personally blame OpenGL for this :)

Here's my rendering code

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
glPushMatrix();

GLuint texture_handle;

/* texture load logic */
...
...


glTranslatef(this->xPos + this->width / 2, this->yPos + this->height / 2, 0.0f);
glRotatef(this->angle, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glTranslatef(-this->width / 2, -this->height / 2 , 0);

/* Creates 3D cube */
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glVertex2f(0, 0);
glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
glVertex2f(this->GetWidth(), 0);
glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
glVertex2f(this->GetWidth(), this->GetHeight());
glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
glVertex2f(0, this->GetHeight());
glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
glEnd();

glDeleteTextures(1, &texture_handle);
glPopMatrix();  
glFlush();
```

For completion, here's Box2D part

```
/* define body for box */
b2BodyDef bodyDef;
bodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
bodyDef.position.Set(this->xPos / RATIO, this->yPos / RATIO);
bodyDef.angle = this->angle * (M_PI / 180);

body = this->world->CreateBody(&bodyDef);

b2PolygonShape box;
box.SetAsBox((this->width / 2) / RATIO, (this->height / 2) / RATIO);

b2FixtureDef shapeDef;
shapeDef.shape = &box;
shapeDef.density = 1f;
shapeDef.friction = 0.8f;

body->CreateFixture(&shapeDef);

this->body = body;


/* apply physics */
b2Vec2 position = this->body->GetPosition();

this->angle = this->body->GetAngle() / (M_PI / 180);

this->xPos = (position.x * RATIO);
this->yPos = (position.y * RATIO);
```

Comment: Does it work, if you swap rotation and translation? So, Translate, Translate, Rotate.

Comment: Just in case you missed it, glRotatef takes degrees, but Box2D's GetAngle will give you radians.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work if I switch rotation and translation, it gets worse. And of course, angle is in degrees :)

Comment: Your glVertex and glTexCoord calls seem to be in the wrong order... tex coord should be set before the vertex is drawn.

Comment: Switched order but nothing changed except that textures are rotated.

Comment: What does Box2D's debug draw show? You can use the one from the testbed, as it's already OpenGL.

Comment: Thanks for the tip with DebugDraw! It shows that box has different angle than one I'm getting from GetAngle() method of the body

Comment: Well I figured it out. First problem was with OpenGl positioning and second problem was my own stupidity. I messed up conversion between degrees and radians (and no one noticd hehe).